# Can I use STUFF FOR XML PATH using a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
DECLARE @InOuts TABLE
    (
        RowID int,
        RowText varchar(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @InOuts ( RowID, RowText ) VALUES
( 1, 'The' ), ( 1, 'Cat' ), ( 1, 'Sat' ), ( 1, 'here' ), ( 2, 'The' ), ( 3, 'Cat' )

SELECT * FROM @InOuts

SELECT  STUFF((    SELECT ',' + @InOuts.RowText

                        FROM @InOuts
                        WHERE
                       RowID = 1
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' )
```

This throws an error:

Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 13

Must declare the scalar variable "@InOuts".

I have run the code without the SELECT STUFF statement (i.e. up to

```
SELECT * FROM @InOuts
```

and it works fine - it returns six rows as expected.

In other words, I don't seem to be able to use STUFF on a temporary table.  If I replace @InOuts and its columns with a table from my database, the script works fine.

Thanks

Edward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an alias for the table name:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + io.RowText
              FROM @InOuts io
              WHERE io.RowID = 1
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '' )
```

SQL Server does not allow table (and column) aliases to begin with an `@`.  The simple solution is to use a simpler alias.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - saved me hours of head-banging.